# How to save text in QLineEdits in PyQt even if the Widget gets closed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qsettings

Hello I have made a GUI for my script using PyQt I have a couple of Line edit ands a couple of buttons

(.....) = (self.(.....).text()) which I use that text for my script as a variable (but I don't think thats important to the question)  I want to be able to type text into the QLineEdits and for it to save so next time I open it the text will still be there

I use PyQt5 then I use Py-installer to make it into an app So I want to be able to save the text inside the QLineEdits and then when It closes for it be be saved there for next time I open it>

Ps. I am sharing this app with other people So I want it to save what that user puts in (they are putting in stuff that is custom to them like for example (name or something like that)

Here is a sample of my pyqt5 code:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to persist the data? In a database, or on disk (in a file)? If the former, what database server do you intend to use? And if the latter, how do you intend to format the saved data--as binary, as plain text, as XML, as JSON, etc.?

Comment: Im not sure exactly what your asking But i have a gui with text boxes in it I just want to open my app and the text that I saved to already be in the QLineEdits for me to use I dont want to store it in any page files or anything like that @nb1987

Comment: Becuase im using a selenium chrome driver script where the text boxes include checkout information that the script out filles for you so I want it to stay there for each users address that they put in @nb1987

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/b1cfd481c2b8627c67060ba3c7e518c4/archive/ac5d8bbbaa36617001436d996b6ea83e9176a601.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an older application, it implements the functions that saved the states of the widgets and restored them.

In order for it to work properly, the application must meet the following requirements:

- You have to set `OrganizationName`, `OrganizationDomain` and `ApplicationName`.
- Each widget that you want to save the state must have an `objectName`
- You must use `restore()` when you want to restore the states, a good option is after creating all the widgets.
- You must use `save()` when you want to save the states, a good place would be `closeEvent()`.

In the next part I show an example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

# for PyQt4 change QtWidget to QtGui and PyQt5 to PyQt4


def restore(settings):
    finfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(settings.fileName())
    if finfo.exists() and finfo.isFile():
        for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
            mo = w.metaObject()
            if w.objectName() and not w.objectName().startswith("qt_"):
                settings.beginGroup(w.objectName())
                for i in range( mo.propertyCount(), mo.propertyOffset()-1, -1):
                    prop = mo.property(i)
                    if prop.isWritable():
                        name = prop.name()
                        val = settings.value(name, w.property(name))
                        if str(val).isdigit():
                            val = int(val)
                        w.setProperty(name, val)
                settings.endGroup()

def save(settings):
    for w in QtWidgets.qApp.allWidgets():
        mo = w.metaObject()
        if w.objectName() and not w.objectName().startswith("qt_"):
            settings.beginGroup(w.objectName())
            for i in range(mo.propertyCount()):
                prop = mo.property(i)
                name = prop.name()
                if prop.isWritable():
                    settings.setValue(name, w.property(name))
            settings.endGroup()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("widget")
        self.init_ui()
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        print(self.settings.fileName())
        restore(self.settings)

    def init_ui(self):
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("label")
        lineEdit1.setObjectName("label")
        lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")
        combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combobox.addItems(["1", "2", "3"])
        combobox.setObjectName("combo")
        lay.addWidget(lineEdit1)
        lay.addWidget(lineEdit2)
        lay.addWidget(combobox)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save(self.settings)
        super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("Eyllanesc")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("eyllanesc.com")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("MyApp")
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:**

In the case that you use Qt Designer it is no longer necessary to place the `objectsName`s because they are already established, but on the other hand the class that provides Qt Designer is not a widget, but a class that is responsible for filling a widget, so we must create the widget to be able to overwrite the `closeEvent` method as shown below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        restore(self.settings)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        save(self.settings)
        super().closeEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationName("Eyllanesc")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setOrganizationDomain("eyllanesc.com")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("MyApp")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169123/discussion-on-answer-by-eyllanesc-how-to-save-text-in-qlineedits-in-pyqt-even-if).

Comment: WOWOWOWOWO IT works thank you so much bro @eyllanesc

Comment: @eyllanesc Just one more question where is this information that you last type in being stored are you receiving it or how does it work exactly?

Comment: execute `print(self.settings.fileName())` after `restore(self.settings)`: `self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()
restore(self.settings)
print(self.settings.fileName())`

Comment: @eyllanesc Hey thanks for all the help and sorry for bothering you again It works perfectly on mac but when I shared my script with a friend that used windows it no longer saves do you think you could look into this?

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj 
I've tried it on Linux, Mac OS and Windows and it works correctly, what version of PyQt5 do you use? What do you get when you run `print(self.settings.fileName())`?

Comment: Well I use pyinstaller So i tried it on pyqt5 10. something and pyqt5 5.9.2 @eyllanesc

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj 
I've also used it with pyinstaller, which you get when you run: `print(self.settings.fileName())`?

Comment: @eyllanesc where would I put that line in the code? after the if __name__ == __main__  ??

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj after of `self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()`.

Comment: @eyllanesc I run the script the gui opens then i type some stuff click some buttons and close it and noting prints at all nor does it save

Comment: but be smart, if you use an executable it will not show anything with the print, save that text in a .txt file, and when you close the application open the .txt file. I recommend you analyze your problem well, first you tell me you want to use print (self.settings.fileName ()) in the main but in the main there is no self, and now this, I'm a bit busy, please take the time to track where is the problem, as I say I have tried it on several OS with or without pyinstaller and keep working