# How do I change the font of qlabel from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a **ini** file which is automatically read whenever my app is opened. I have a **font_heading** variable inside the **ini** file to store the font of heading label of my app.
The **font_heading** variable stores the result of **QtGui.QFontDialog.getFont().toString()**. I want to change the font of heading label according to the value inside the **font_heading** variable whenever my app loads. How do I do it?

Comment: Use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html).

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837565/how-to-save-text-in-qlineedits-in-pyqt-even-if-the-widget-gets-closed